# Prove that $n (3^{1/n} - 1) > 1$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$!

Tags: inequality

I've been trying to prove that $(n+1)^n \leq 3n^n$ and got down to prove that $n(3^{1/n}-1)>1$, but I can't go further from here, can anyone pls help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks I'll make sure to make future questions better :)

Comment: @QApps I have edited the question. Please let me know if I have done it correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$3^{x}>e^{x}=1+\frac x {1!}+\frac {x^{2}} {2!}+...$$ so $3^{x}>1+x$ for all positive numbers $x$.

Take $x=\frac 1 n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm actually not allowed to use e :/

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Your inequality is equivalent to 
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\le 3$$, think about the Euler number $e$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm actually not allowed to use it

Answer (score 0):

You can write $$n\left(3^\frac{1}{n}-1\right)=n \left(e^{\frac{1}{n}\log 3}-1 \right).$$Then your claim follows from $$e^y > 1+y,\quad y \neq 0$$ and the fact that $\log 3 > 1$.

Comment: I suppose the idea is to give an upper bound on $e$, which is yet to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $s_n=(1+\frac 1n)^{(n+1)}$

Show that:

$(i)$ $s_n$ is decreasing, and

$(ii)$ $\forall n, s_n>t_n$, where $t_n = (1+\frac 1n)^n$

Edit:

Prove the following too:

$t_n$ is increasing. This helps you avoid too many menial calculations.

Comment: how is this going to help solve the problem though?

Comment: We have $s_5<3$.

Comment: From my edit, it then follows that $\forall n$, we have $t_n<3$

Comment: oh ok,I used a similar idea, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

$f:x\mapsto 3^x$ is a convex function, hence the graph of $3^x$ lies above the tangent line at the origin.
This implies $3^x\geq 1+x\log 3$, and for any $x>0$ we have $3^x>1+x$ since $e<3$.
 The claim follows by evaluating the inequality $3^x>1+x$ at $x=\frac{1}{n}$.